# Symmetric part of a 4th rank tensor in mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, tensors

I am quite new to Mathematica and would like to know how to compute the symmetric part of a 4th order tensor $A_{ijkl}$.

Since there are 4 indices (i,j,k,l), we have 4!=24 permutations.

The symmetric part of this is given by:

$\frac{1}{24} (T_{ijkl}+T_{jikl}+T_{ijlk}+T_{jilk}+T_{klij}+T_{lkij}+T_{klji}+T_{lkji}+T_{ikjl}+T_{kijl}+T_{iklj}+T_{kilj}+T_{jlik}+T_{ljik}+T_{jlki}+T_{ljki}+T_{iljk}+T_{lijk}+T_{ilkj}+T_{likj}+T_{jkil}+T_{kjil}+T_{jkli}+T_{kjli})$

If $$A_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad A_{kl}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then

$$A_{ijkl}=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 \\
0 & 0 &1 
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
1 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0 \\
0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix} \\
= \begin{bmatrix} 
1.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 1.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 1. \\
 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.\\
 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.\\ 
0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.\\ 
1.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 1.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 1.\\ 
0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.\\ 
0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.\\
 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 0.\\
 1.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 1.& 0.& 0.& 0.& 1.\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and finally
$SymmetricPart(A_{ijkl})=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} \\ 0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 \\ 0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\ \frac{1}{3}& 0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} \\ 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 \\ 0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 \\ \frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &0 &0 &0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$

I would like to do this in a symbolic computation...

Currently , I have:

```
(*Needs["SymbolicC`"]*)
tensorA := Array[a,{3,3},0];
tensorB := Array[b,{3,3},0];

(*computes the 4th rank tensor*)
tmp = tensorProduct[tensorA, tensorB);
result = TensorSymmetry[tmp]
```

But the output is empty... can anyone give me a hand with this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define a symbolic rank 4 tensor (of dimension 3):

```
MatrixForm[symbolicRank4=Array[Subscript[a,StringJoin[ToString/@{##}]]&,{3,3,3,3}]]
```

We can symmetrize this manually using the permutations you suggest:

```
MatrixForm[manualSymmetrization=Simplify[Mean[TensorTranspose[symbolicRank4,#]&/@Permutations[Range[4]]]]]
```

or using the built-in `Symmetrize`:

```
MatrixForm[builtInSymmetrization=Normal[Symmetrize[symbolicRank4,Symmetric[All]]]]
```

These indeed agree, and get recognized by `TensorSymmetry`

```
In[54]:= builtInSymmetrization == manualSymmetrization
TensorSymmetry[builtInSymmetrization]

Out[54]= True

Out[55]= Symmetric[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Finally, if you care for the *independent* tensor components, you can use `SymmetrizedArray` directly:

```
MatrixForm[SymmetrizedArray[pos_:>Subscript[a,StringJoin[ToString/@pos]],{3,3,3,3},Symmetric[All]]]
```

[image]

The particular examples given in the post can be symmetrized as:

```
MatrixForm[Symmetrize[TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[3],IdentityMatrix[3]],Symmetric[All]]]
MatrixForm[Symmetrize[TensorProduct[Array[a,{3,3}],Array[b,{3,3}]],Symmetric[All]]]
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Varnavides,
Thank you for the reply.
Would you be so kind as to tell me, how to evaluate a symbolic expression to see if the code gets the same values I am getting

Comment: Does the edit with your particular examples help? If your're asking how to interpret the `SymmetrizedArray[]` objects, you can convert them to lists of lists by wrapping them in `Normal[]`.